# Custom QWidget: setGeometry() not working when called within from within itself

Tags: c++, qt, class, qwidget, updating

My problem is this: when calling setGeometry() from within my own QWidget, it doesn't visually update in my scene, but if I call the function directly within my main window it will update.

For example, in my main window, if I call for example:

```
MyWidget->customFunction(varX, varY, varW, varH);
```

And the code for the function within the widget:

```
void MyWidget::customFunction(int x, int y, int w, int h)
{
     //other calculations
     this->setGeometry(x,y,w,h);
}
```

Then I don't see any changes in my application
However if I fetch the coordinates of the widget they are where the widget should be in 2D Space, but it is just invisible or something

Now if I just call this line within my main window, then there is no problem:

```
MyWidget->setGeometry(varX, varY, varW, varH);
```

I don't understand why the way I want isn't working

I'm not currently overloading the function for setGeometry(), and I'm not altering any of the variables within my custom function. I've figured this out because I can still use the function move() within my widget instead of setGeometry(), but if I want to both move it and change it's size I'd then have to call 2 different functions instead of just 1.
With that said, this is just an inconvenience that I don't understand and want to solve it in case it becomes an issue later on.